# How can I keep scoll position on dynamic refresh div?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, scroll

I'm searching a few hours ago for this, I can't finr anywhere.

I use simple Jquery script to refresh a div. I want to see my PHP output in that div.

```
$script = " 

<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>   
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#uziRefresh').load('http://mypage/refresh.php?a_a=".$kinek[1]."');
}, 6000); // the \"3000\" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
});
// ]]></script>

";
```

My problem is. When it refreshing it go to top position of div scroll. I would like to keep the current position, becouse my users my would like to read all content of the div. I would like to make a simple chat application. But it's bad cos always go to top.

How can I solve this? Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
setInterval(function() {
var div = document.getElementById("uzidoboz").scrollTop; 
$('#uziRefresh').load('/modulok/belso_levelezes/refresh.php?a_a=<?php print($kinek[1])?>', function(){ 
$("div.uzidoboz").scrollTop(div);
})
}, 6000);
});
</script>
```

This is my full solution. I'm sorry, I missed some div names, but with correct names the last solution not yet worked. This work fine. First I get the current scrolltop, reload the div, and set the scrolltop.

It runs in every 6000 millisecond. It's simple now and work. I have my divs. uzidoboz div have got overflow. My content is in that. But I load it all to the uziRefresh div...

Comment: Thanks, a variant of this worked for me. Just one thing though, the line `$("div.uzidoboz").scrollTop(div);` didn't work for me until I changed 'div.' to '#': so `$("#uzidoboz").scrollTop(div);` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution. I have removed your comments sorry!.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    var updateScrollPosition = function() {
        var div = $('#uziRefresh');
        div.scrollTop(div.height());
    };


    setInterval(function() {
        $('#uziRefresh').load('http://mypage/refresh.php?a_a=".$kinek[1]."', updateScrollPosition);
    }, 6000);
});
```

To be precise use this -

> $script = "
>
> ```
> <script type=\"text/javascript\">// <![CDATA[
> ```
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     cache: false
> });
>
> var updateScrollPosition = function() {
>     var div = $('#uziRefresh');
>     div.scrollTop(div.height());
> };
>
>
> setInterval(function() {
>     $('#uziRefresh').load('http://mypage/refresh.php?a_a=".$kinek[1]."',
> ```
>
> updateScrollPosition);
>       }, 6000); // ]]>
>
> ";

Comment: But it's mean the document. I only refresh a scrollable div.

Comment: You want to maintain the position in the scrollable div?

Comment: Yes.. I refresh the the content of the div. I "include" a php file output. But when it refresh it goes to top.. :-( .. Now I tried this: `<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js\"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scollPos() { 
            var div = document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollTop;
            document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML = div;
        document.getElementById('uziRefresh').scrollTop  = div;     
        }
    </script>` .. Not work. :( I got the position, but not set...

Comment: Your jquery file is probably not loaded properly

Comment: Ok... It exactly do what the first solution did. The scroolbar move up on refresh. It dont keep the actual position of div scrool.